# Ubuntu 14.04 keeps asking for passphrase when ssh

Tags: ssh, svn, passphrase

I have ubuntu 14.04 workstation installed in my LAB. Now I have issue with rsa key passphrase.

Following are what I have in my LAB

- **SVN server(12.04):**  I have svn server installed, anyone who want to
  access svn must have their key in `authorized_keys` file of svn server.
- **Home Server(12.04):**  It's mounted as `/home` on clients
- **Ubuntu Desktop 12.04:**  There are more than 5 clients connected to my ubuntu lab (using for many years)
- **Ubuntu Desktop 14.04:**  I have just installed 14.04 version for test

This my issue,

- From **Ubuntu Desktop 12.04** it doesn't ask for passphrase but **Ubuntu 14.04** does. It keeps asking for passphrase everytime I use SVN command.
- I tried recreated rsa key but it doesn't work.
- I test created key without passphrase, it doesn't ask me to enter
  passphrase. And it isn't what I want because unsecured.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: In my case the GUI keychain agent for Ubuntu had stopped running somehow. I restarted and the first attempt it popped up and asked me my passphrase and then remembered it afterwards. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p85xwZ_OLX0

Comment: There's no problem since I decided to upgrade client to 16.04

Answer (score 3):

You may be affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1271591).

If this is the case, you have the wrong ssh-agent set as active. You can check this with the command

```
$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

If the agent value begins `/tmp/ssh`, you have the commandline `ssh-agent` acting as your agent.

As a workaround, you can use the old style shell command

```
$ ssh-add
```

to add you key to the keyring. This does not work well with all graphical programs, however.

Comment: The updates to that bug show that the issue has been fixed in gnome-keyring-3.10.1-1ubuntu5.  It would appear that the latest gnome-keyring package is 3.10.1-1ubuntu4, so that bugfix has still not been released.  However, this comment shows how to apply the fix manually: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1271591/comments/13

Comment: I have the same problem, and the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is set as expected. (`/run/user/1000/keyring-.../ssh`). So what gives? Because ssh still asks me for the password in the terminal instead of the little keyring popup

Comment: @AlexisWilke in that case you might want to ask a new question.

Comment: I did, it's here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170750/is-there-a-way-to-specify-the-list-of-private-keys-to-add-to-ssh-agent/170752#170752

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the issue by adding the following lines in my "~/.bashrc"

```
eval `gnome-keyring-daemon --start`
USERNAME="reynold"
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$(ls /run/user/$(id -u $USERNAME)/keyring*/ssh|head -1)"
export SSH_AGENT_PID="$(pgrep gnome-keyring)"
```

Comment: Finally, the answer I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to find a solution for this annoying problem (Ubuntu server 14.04) in [Atlassian support](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678) - step #4. It appears like the ssh-agent was running by default.

Open a terminal window and enter the following command to see if the agent is running:

```
ps -e  | grep [s]sh-agent
```

If the agent isn't running, start it manually with the following command:

```
ssh-agent /bin/bash
```

Load your new identity into the ssh-agent management program using the ssh-add command.

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /Users/manthony/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /Users/manthony/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/manthony/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

Use `ssh-add` to list the keys that the agent is managing.

```
$ ssh-add -l
```