# Disable asking for passphrase key ssh

Tags: ssh, encryption, lxde

I have installed `LXDE` on my ubuntu 16.04 and now every time that I want to ssh to my servers I get this message:
`Enter passphrase for key '/home/emadhelmi/.ssh/id_rsa':` with `unity` desktop never I asked for this passphrase. I also do this command lines:

```
exec ssh-agent bash
ssh-add
```

But when I start a new terminal I must again do these lines.
Also, I do whatever said in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487506/ubuntu-14-04-keeps-asking-for-passphrase-when-ssh) and add this to my `.bashrc`:

```
eval `gnome-keyring-daemon --start`
USERNAME="reynold"
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$(ls /run/user/$(id -u $USERNAME)/keyring*/ssh|head -1)"
export SSH_AGENT_PID="$(pgrep gnome-keyring)"
```

But at the startup of my os, I must enter the passphrase. How can I fix this and make LXDE like my ubuntu?